# jQuery show/hide with callback animates (dont want it)

Tags: jquery, animation

When I add callback to show/hide, my element starts to animate. I dont want it. I just need to add a function AFTER show/hide is finished.

I cannot nullify time, cause i use option-based function (element CAN be animated, but if its not wanted, it must just show-hide. With callback attached to it, it does not work :(

Is there a neat trick to elliminate animation on show/hide?
OR is there another way to add a function AFTER animation has finished?

Thanks in advance!

**Found the solution! Just do:**

```
show('','', function()...
```

Comment: Please supply you javascript...

Comment: BTW: use `hide()` or `show()` and then the callback, that's all you need. But I would like to see what you have so far.

Comment: The whole point of the callbacks is for specifically waiting on animations to complete. If you are not animating, the callbacks aren't needed for that. Just call the function.

Comment: Inside plugin, there is:

    select.appendTo('body')[options.open](function() ...

options.open can be show(), fadeIn(), slideDown etc. When I have show(), I don't want it to slide, fade or whatever it does. when you call out show() without any parameters, it does not animate. when you call out fadeIn(), without parameters, it fades in. When I add parameter to show() it starts to animate. I understand it should do it when i add parameter for duartion, but I don't :(


    select.appendTo('body')[options.open]() works perfectly.

Answer (score 18):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

```
.show( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )
```

To specifically disable the animation, set it's duration to zero and no easing:

```
.show(0,'', function(){
    //your code here
});
```