# Callback function to be executed after jQuery show / hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In iOS, the following code has a noticeable flicker between the hide() and the scrollBy():

```
element.hide();
window.scrollBy(0, -elementHeight);
```

This is because toggling between display: none and display: block on iOS is a heavy task, as if the elements are being added to and removed from the DOM.

I need a way to perform window.scrollBy() as a callback, once the hide() has successfully completed and the DOM has updated.  Is there a way to do this in jQuery?

Comment: Just read the documenation.  element.hide(callback);  *facepalm*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769475/jquery-show-hide-with-callback-animates-dont-want-it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either pass a duration and a callback, or just pass a callback option, like this:

```
element.hide(0, some_function);

// or 

element.hide({done: some_function});
```

By default, the second option takes 400 ms. To do it immediately, use one of these:

```
element.hide(0, some_function);

// or 

element.hide({duration: 0, done: some_function});
```

[Here's a jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/tmjuLsx0/).

[See the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery api:

> .hide(options)
>
> complete 
>   Type: Function() 
>   A function to call once the animation is complete.

Try this:

> element.hide({complete: function(){
>   window.scrollBy(0, -elementHeight); });